# active class link in joomla

Tags: css, joomla

Hi I'm trying to make a joomla site here, only one problem I can't seem to figure out. The color of my active link doesn't change, it has an image and a color, the image is in place as it should be, but the color doesn't change. Anyone an idea? here's the css:

```
a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  }

a:link, a:visited {color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;}

a:focus, a:hover {
  color: #e2231a;
  text-decoration: none;
  }

#links li.active {
  color: #e2231a;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("../images/hover.png") bottom center no-repeat;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  }
```

I know the active statement looks different then the rest, but this was the only way to get my image to show. Really stuck on this..

Answer (score 0):

Used to this for `a` **tag**

```
#links li.active a {
  // here style for your anchor link 
}
```

Comment: haha wauw, that was pretty stupid, tried a lot of things, except that :D thanks it works :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the list elements within Links to change when active use this.

```
#links li:active a {color:#000;}
```

If you want all lists to be effected by this change use

```
li:active a {color:#000;}
```

If you want more than just the li elements to change ie ever single link on the site that is active to obey these rules then use the following

```
a:active {color:#000;}
```

Hope this helps you out.